# Graphaware Framework and UUID not starting on Neo4j GrapheneDB

Tags: neo4j, graphaware, graphenedb

I am trying to get the Graphaware Framework and UUID running on a GrapheneDB instance. I have followed the instructions to zip the JAR and neo4j.properties files and uploaded using the GrapheneDB Web Interface but UUID's are not added when I create a new node.

neo4j.properties file

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware

com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

#UIDM becomes the module ID:
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.1=com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper

#optional, default is uuid:
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty=uuid

#optional, default is false:
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.stripHyphens=true

#optional, default is all nodes:
#com.graphaware.module.UIDM.node=hasLabel('Label1') || hasLabel('Label2')

#optional, default is no relationships:
#com.graphaware.module.UIDM.relationship=isType('Type1')
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.relationship=com.graphaware.runtime.policy.all.IncludeAllBusinessRelationships

#optional, default is uuidIndex
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidIndex=uuidIndex

#optional, default is uuidRelIndex
com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidRelationshipIndex=uuidRelIndex
```

Log Output

> 2017-03-02 10:20:40.184+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by
>   request 2017-03-02 10:20:40.209+0000 INFO 
>   [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper] stopped 2017-03-02
>   10:20:40.209+0000 INFO  Stopping... 2017-03-02 10:20:40.982+0000 INFO 
>   Stopped. 2017-03-02 10:20:43.402+0000 INFO  Starting... 2017-03-02
>   10:20:43.820+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7475. 2017-03-02
>   10:20:45.153+0000 INFO  [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] GraphAware
>   Runtime disabled. 2017-03-02 10:20:48.130+0000 INFO  Started.
>   2017-03-02 10:20:48.343+0000 INFO 
>   [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareServerBootstrapper] started 2017-03-02
>   10:20:48.350+0000 INFO  Mounted unmanaged extension
>   [com.graphaware.server] at [/graphaware] 2017-03-02 10:20:48.724+0000
>   INFO  Mounting GraphAware Framework at /graphaware 2017-03-02
>   10:20:48.755+0000 INFO  Will try to scan the following packages:
>   {com.**.graphaware.**,org.**.graphaware.**,net.**.graphaware.**}
>   2017-03-02 10:20:52.633+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at
>   http://localhost:7474/

Messages.log Extract

> 2017-03-02 10:33:59.991+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] ---
>   STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles END ---
>   2017-03-02 10:34:01.846+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] ---
>   SERVER STARTED START --- 2017-03-02 10:34:02.526+0000 INFO 
>   [c.g.s.f.b.GraphAwareBootstrappingFilter] Mounting GraphAware
>   Framework at /graphaware 2017-03-02 10:34:02.547+0000 INFO 
>   [c.g.s.f.c.GraphAwareWebContextCreator] Will try to scan the following
>   packages:
>   {com.**.graphaware.**,org.**.graphaware.**,net.**.graphaware.**}
>   2017-03-02 10:34:06.100+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] ---
>   SERVER STARTED END ---

It looks like the framework is not started but I have set enabled=true in the properties file.

**Environment Setup**

- Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.1
- graphaware-server-3.1.0.44
- graphaware-uuid-3.1.0.44.13

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify the neo4j version and the framework + module versions you deployed to graphenedb as well as your complete config file

Comment: I added the neo4j version and the framework + module versions to the end of my question above. I can't figure out how to pull the config file down from GrapheneDB. Th eonly changes I have made to the default GrapheneDB instance though is to add neo4j.properties file I uploaded above.

Comment: We're working on 3.1 compatibility issues. Will update here when fixed.

Comment: Fixed for Neo4j 3.1.3, please download latest versions here: https://products.graphaware.com/

Comment: thanks a lot for confirming